# What does "user" mean what they say ANDROID_D is unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device

Tags: android

From android documentation,

> ANDROID_ID

On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device.

Here what does "user" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Later in the same [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID):

> On devices that have [multiple users](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2#MultipleUsers), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the `ANDROID_ID` value is unique to each user.

And following the link there:

> Android now allows multiple user spaces on shareable devices such as tablets. Each user on a device has their own set of accounts, apps, system settings, files, and any other user-associated data

Comment: Thanks @Sadhik and laalto for your replies. So in this context, user means linux user which enables the device owner to use it.? I have read about that android creates a user for each application. So I'm wondering which user is used for generating ANDROID_ID

Comment: Each Android app installation is sandboxed as a linux user, so there are many linux users to begin with for each device-level user. I haven't looked into it but it would make sense to use similar mechanisms for sandboxing device users from each other. As it comes to ANDROID_ID, "user" means the device user, not a linux user.

Answer (score 0):

unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID.